# Will Lua allow me to "read in" the text from the Wireshark Filter text box?

Tags: filter, lua, wireshark

I wish to write an app that reads whatever filter criteria is in the Wireshark filter text box and then manipulate it using Lua.  Does anyone know if that is possible?  I would like to know if it is possible before I get to deep into learning Lua and using it with Wireshark.

Thanks!
Joe

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't read it, but you can set the filter and apply it to the current capture. See the [GUI Support](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/lua_module_Gui.html#non_method_functions_Gui) section in the Wireshark docs.

To set the text of the display filter textbox, use `set_filter(text)`.
To apply the current text of the display filter (make it take effect), use `apply_filter()`.

Avoid calling `apply_filter()` from within a dissector (infinite loop can occur from re-invoking the dissector). The function is better suited in a menu action or a button action.

**EDIT**: To add your own `get_filter()` Lua function to Wireshark's Lua API (**untested**):

1. Add a function named `funnel_get_filter()` in [`funnel_stat.c`](http://anonsvn.wireshark.org/viewvc/trunk-1.6/gtk/funnel_stat.c?revision=37146&view=markup) (see line 468 for example).
2. Add `get_filter` to `funnel_ops_t` ([`funnel.h:80`](http://anonsvn.wireshark.org/viewvc/trunk-1.6/epan/funnel.h?revision=37146&view=markup)).
3. Add    `funnel_get_filter` to `funnel_ops` at [`funnel_stat.c:546`](http://anonsvn.wireshark.org/viewvc/trunk-1.6/gtk/funnel_stat.c?revision=37146&view=markup) and at [`tap-funnel.c:90`](http://anonsvn.wireshark.org/viewvc/trunk-1.6/tap-funnel.c?revision=37146&view=markup). Make sure you add it at the correct array index according to `funnel_ops_t`.
4. Copy the code below to [`wslua_gui.c`](http://anonsvn.wireshark.org/viewvc/trunk-1.6/epan/wslua/wslua_gui.c?revision=37146&view=markup) and then compile:

`/* TODO: Test me!! */`

```
WSLUA_FUNCTION wslua_get_filter(lua_State* L) { /* Get the text of the display filter textbox */
    const gchar* text;
    text = ops->get_filter();
    lua_pushstring(L,text);
    WSLUA_RETURN(1); /* The display filter textbox's text. */
}
```

Comment: That is unfortunate.  I really need to read the existing filter text (if any) without otherwise impacting standard workflow for my app.  I originally considered modifying the Wireshark source for this purpose.  Adding this function to the Lua interface would be much easier I believe.  Do you have any pointers on adding this as a new Lua function?

Comment: Edited answer to add `get_filter` to Wireshark Lua API. Let me know if it works.